# PHP For Loop N Times Based On Array Length

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have this array :

```
$products = array('0', '1', '2', '3');
```

and I want to have this combination :

```
0
0,1
0,1,2
0,1,2,3 // my code can't show this result
0,1,3 // my code can't show this result
0,2
0,2,3
0,3
1
1,2
1,2,3
1,3
2
2,3
3
```

and here's my code :

```
$rows = count($products);
for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {

    echo $i . '<br>';

    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $rows; $j++){
        echo $i . $j . '<br>';

        if (!empty($products[$j+1])) {
            echo $i . $j . $products[$j+1] . '<br>';
        }

    }

}
```

but, unfortunately I missed 2 results :

```
0,1,2,3
0,1,3
```

and I still have doubt about this `for` loop inside loop, while the number of combination is determined by array length.

how to get that missed combination and perfectly works for different array length?

Comment: Why not use `foreach`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    <?php
        $set = array('0', '1', '2','3');
        $power_set = possible_set($set);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($power_set);
        echo "</pre>";
        function possible_set($array) {
            $results = array(array( ));
            foreach ($array as $element)
                foreach ($results as $inner_element)
                    array_push($results, array_merge(array($element), $inner_element));

            unset($results[0]);
            $results = array_values($results);
            return $results;
        }
    ?>
```

https://eval.in/516963

Comment: by the way, why your code always gives me empty array on index[0]?

Comment: Because I my code I have created an empty array and then pushing value , BTW have edited now.

Answer (score 3):

```
$products = array('0', '1', '2', '3');

    $rows = count($products);  //missing here array count......

    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {

        echo $i . '<br>';

        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $rows; $j++){
            echo $i . $j . '<br>';

            if (!empty($products[$j+1])) {
                echo $i . $j . $products[$j+1] . '<br>';
            }

        }

    }
```